# fopen file error: frequently write a file

Tags: c++, file, fopen

I have a recieve thread, when messages from different src coming, the thread will open a file, and update it with message content. Now I encountered a problem, my log get error messages “open file error" as below:

> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.222 I Thread2821 Receive message: src= 5
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.223 I Thread2821 Receive message: src= 0
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 I Thread2821 Receive message: src= 1
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 E Thread2821 Error Opening ** file: C:\writting.txt
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 I Thread2821 Receive message: src= 2
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 E Thread2821 Error Opening ** file: C:\writting.txt
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 I Thread2821 Receive message: src= 3
>
> 2018/04/26 10:28:44.482 E Thread2821 Error Opening ** file: C:\writting.txt

the code structure is very old, it didn't use message queue. From the log, messages from src1/2/3, open the file at the same time.

the thread code:

```
Receiver::Run(){
    if( Msg.ReadStream(buffer, nLen))
     {
        pMsg = messageFactory().CreateMessage(Msg);
        ...
        parentThread->ProcessMessage(pMsg); // update file here
     } }
```

Is there a explanation why the thread fopen the file at the same time? What senario may cause this problem. I think it should have a time difference at least.

Comment: It seems you don't have any synchronization between threads. Either you need to add synchronization (e.g. mutexes or similar) or create a new thread which does all the writing to the file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, it's pretty unclear what is going on and where, and what /you/ consider wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I checked the code again, the recieve thread passthrough the messages to another thread B, B does the writing operations,and I didn't find synchronization. I don't understand clearly why the thread B could open the file at the same time even if the writing operations are triggered by different messages.